# Is it correct to say "tell me the location I need to go to to get the document"?

Tags: american-english, phrase-choice

Is it correct to say *tell me the location I need to go to to get the document* or do I have to say *tell me the location I need to go to get the document*?

Comment: In real spoken contexts, native speakers wouldn't even *notice* the repetition of ***to***, because (1) - they're different parts of speech (preposition and infinitive marker) and (2) - they *sound* different (the preposition will be fully enunciated, while the infinitive marker is reduced to the "neutral vowel" schwa). But *syntactically*, they're both ***required***, so all native speakers would notice if you omitted one (they'd assume you omitted the *infinitive marker*, because as a non-native speaker you'd be practically *bound* to articulate the single instance you *did* include! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need both "to"s. But it does sound a little odd, doesn't it? You could simplify it as "Tell me where I need to go to get the document."

But if you kept the original form, the first "to" is needed to connect "go" to "the location," since that's how that usage works. We can omit "to" when the object of "go" is a preposition ("I go *there*"), but we need it when it's a noun ("I go *to the store*"). If we un-inverted the syntax, we realize it would be missing if we said "I need to *go the location* to get the document."